# Second order ODE with constant coeffiecient?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is the [involved method](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf) for finding the solution to homogenous ODE required, or is there a shortcut, given the lack of functions of x?

$$\ y'' + ay'=b$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let $z = y'$ which will reduce the order by 1 and make it trivial and then then integrate to get $y$...

Answer (score 1):

Considering the problem $$\ y'' + ay'=b$$ you can easily go back to much simpler solutions since $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Rewrite the equation as $$y''+a(y'-\frac ba)=0$$ and now define $z=y'-\frac ba$ which makes $$z'+a z=0$$ the simplest first order differentiatial equation. Solve it for $z$ $$z=c_1 \,e^{-a x}$$ and replace $$y'-\frac ba=c_1 \,e^{-a x}$$ $$y'=\frac ba+c_1 \,e^{-a x}$$ and just integrate one more to get the final solution..

Answer (score 0):

The method you sent in the link is what is normally used for 2nd order ODE's, but in this case you can say $a = y'$, and thus reduce the order of the equation.

Please note this equation is not a homogeneous equation, unless b = 0.